# SQLite3 update not working

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I'm trying to perform an update command to my sqlite3 table. But it's not working:

```
+(void)updateContact:(Contact *)c withOriginalFirst:(NSString *)originalFirst originalLast:(NSString *)originalLast originalBriefDescription:(NSString *)originalBriefDescription {

    sqlite3 *database;
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *cmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update contacts set first='%@', last='%@', briefDescription='%@' where first='%@' and last='%@' and briefDescription='%@';",
                         [c first],[c last],[c briefDescription],originalFirst,originalLast,originalBriefDescription];
        const char * sql = [cmd UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            NSLog(@"updateContact SUCCESS - executed command %@",cmd);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"updateContact FAILED - failed to execute command %@",cmd);
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"pdateContact FAILED - failed to open database");
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);

    NSLog(@"After update, contacts = %@",[SQLMaster getContactsFromDatabase]);

}
```

I see "updateContact SUCCESS - executed command ..." printed. But the table is not being updated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

Where is your databasePath pointing? Be sure it is pointing to the documents path in the bundle, and not an external db in the project directly. Also, ensure you put the step statement correctly.

```
+(void)updateContact:(Contact *)c withOriginalFirst:(NSString *)originalFirst originalLast:(NSString *)originalLast originalBriefDescription:(NSString *)originalBriefDescription {

sqlite3 *database;
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    NSString *cmd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update contacts set first='%@', last='%@', briefDescription='%@' where first='%@' and last='%@' and briefDescription='%@';",
                     [c first],[c last],[c briefDescription],originalFirst,originalLast,originalBriefDescription];
    const char * sql = [cmd UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_step(compiledStatement); // Here is the added step.
        NSLog(@"updateContact SUCCESS - executed command %@",cmd);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"updateContact FAILED - failed to execute command %@",cmd);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

}
else {
    NSLog(@"pdateContact FAILED - failed to open database");
}

    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSLog(@"After update, contacts = %@",[SQLMaster getContactsFromDatabase]);

}
```

Also, I see from the line [SQLMaster getContactsFromDatabase] that you are calling other database methods. Be sure that sqlite3_finalize is being reached on all of these database calls, or the database may not release the busy handler.

Comment: do I have to recreate the database everytime this happens? or should restarting the application end connections to the databse. I did everything you said. and this is the first database call I make. the databasepath is correct. what else could it be? I just don't get it.

Comment: Unless the data was hand populated on the device (and sometimes even then), I always delete the application bundle from the device or simulator anytime I've made significant application changes or changes to the database functionality. This will migrate a fresh copy of the db to your simulator or device. I find this to be the safest method.

Comment: should I close the database everytime too?

Comment: That's dependent. If you are frequently calling the database and a lot of rows, this might impact performance, as it caches data. Closing the database will release the cache. If you call your database infrequently or are not working with much data, then you should be okay leaving your database connection open until the application closes. Just be sure you are reseting and finalizing your statements regularly.

Comment: You can also help performance if you modify the cache size. You can do this with the following code after you initialize your database:

     const char *pragma = "PRAGMA cache_size = 25";
    if (sqlite3_exec(database, pragma, NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
    // NSAssert1 message
}

Answer (score 2):

this may help you...

```
  +(void)updateContact:(Contact *)c withOriginalFirst:(NSString *)originalFirst originalLast:(NSString *)originalLast originalBriefDescription:(NSString *)originalBriefDescription 

    {
    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String],&myDatabase)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStmt;
    NSString  *sqlStmt=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE contacts SET first =?, last =? , briefDescription =?, briefDescription =? WHERE first=?,last=?,briefDescription=?;"];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, [sqlStmt UTF8String],-1,&compiledStmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {

         NSLog(@"updateding......cycle");
    sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStmt,1, [[c first] UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStmt,2, [[c last] UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

     sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStmt,3, [[c briefDescription] UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);  

   sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStmt,4, [originalFirst UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

   sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStmt,5, [originalLast UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStmt,6, [originalBriefDescription UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    }
    sqlite3_step(compiledStmt);
    sqlite3_close(database);
}



  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You prepared the statement but did not execute it.  Try int sqlite3_step(sqlite3_stmt*); after the prepare.

Comment: SQLITE_BUSY means that the database engine was unable to acquire the database locks it needs to do its job.  Is there another process accessing the database file or do you have other connections to the database?

Comment: it's not working. why would it be locked? there is nothing else accessing this database.

Comment: Two similar reports on iphone.  Restarting the device fixed one. [thread 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964207/sqlite-exception-sqlite-busy) [thread 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364426/sqlite-busy-error)

Comment: The restart did not work. I restarted my computer and phone. Also, I already had the finalize call.